# How do I create an #ifdef command to differentiate between my two targets in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hopefully this is a simple question to answer - I think I'm being a n00b here.

I have, for the first time, created an XCode project with two targets.  But I now want to add some code to differentiate between my two targets.

```
#ifdef MyTargetOne
    x = 1;

#ifdef MyTargetTwo
   x = 2;
```

I have two targets, but where do I declare "MyTarget1" and "MyTarget2"??

THANKS GUYS!

Comment: And note that, as a general convention, defined names should be, eg, "MY_TARGET_1" and "MY_TARGET_2".  (It's a rule that can be broken for good reason on occasion, but this isn't one of them.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each target you need a target-specific define - you can use the `Preprocessor Macros` setting for this (`[GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS, -D]`) - add `MyTargetOne=1` in the first target and `MyTargetTwo=1` in the second.

Comment: scuse me, but i don't find Preprocessor Macros in Build Settings of each Target. I find it only in Project's Build Setting

Comment: @JackTurky: the exact locations for the target settings depend on what version of Xcode you are using (Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 are very different in this respect) - if you can't find it then post a new question stating what version of Xcode you are using

Comment: done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848263/how-to-differentiate-multiple-targets-on-xcode-4-2